# Selecting one cell falsely marks several other cells as "selected"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I have a UITableView which consists of multiple custom UITableViewCells. In my storyboard I ticked Single Selection because I only want one selected cell at a time. In my ViewController I override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    TextsTableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    selectedCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.chosenTextId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[selectedCell tag]];
    self.chosenStaticText = [selectedCell.textLabel text];
    NSLog(@"The textID: %@ and the text: %@", self.chosenTextId, self.chosenStaticText);
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    TextsTableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    selectedCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.chosenTextId = nil;
    self.chosenStaticText = nil;
}
```

As long as I am not scrolling everything seems to be working fine (although I can't check this without scrolling). My logs only contain the correctly selected cells I clicked. But when I scroll down there are other cells which are selected, too. Does anybody know what might go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is your `UITableViewCell`'s are being reused and this keeps their state, hence why this only happens when you're scrolling. You need to store your selected cells indexPaths in a storage collection object like `NSMutableArray`. Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can check if the cell should be selected and if it is, select it, if it isn't make sure its not selected.

Comment: If would suggest you keep the index path the array not the cell

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need an array when there can only be one selected cell at a time?

Comment: No, you can use an instance variable if you like if there is just one selection. Remember to mark this answer as correct if it helped you; this helps others too. And you're welcome, happy coding!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I can't get it to work. (I marked your answer as accepted because it seemed to work but my testing methods were incomplete). I check my global NSIndexPath variable in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and this seems to work correctly (debugging says everything is ok).  But anyway I have wrongly selected cells. Do you have another idea how to solve / correctly debug my problem?

Comment: Update your question with your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, please.